# In ARMA model, the white noise is uncorrelated, but why there are autocorrelation existing between them?

Tags: time-series, arima, white-noise

I learnt the ARMA model allows the autocorrelation between noise. but I check the definition of white noise is a sequence of uncorrelated, fixed mean random variables. how can the uncorrelated random variables have autocorrelation? please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We always have autocorrelation. However, original ARMA model assumes white noise; so, the autocorrelation is dirac-delta function, i.e. $\delta_k=0$, if $k\neq0$. If whiteness is violated, it'd modify the original model and require a different analytical treatment. In other words, if an ARMA model in a statistical toolbox/or library allows autocorrelated error terms, it's no longer the classical ARMA, rather a modified version of it.

There is a section called [Notes about the error terms section](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model#/Note_about_the_error_terms) in the wiki page:

> The error terms $\varepsilon_{t}$ are generally assumed to be independent identically distributed random variables (i.i.d.) sampled from a normal distribution with zero mean: $\varepsilon_{t} \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ where $\sigma^2$ is the variance. These assumptions may be weakened but doing so will change the properties of the model. In particular, a change to the i.i.d. assumption would make a rather fundamental difference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. appreciate your shared knowledge for this post and my previous post. So my understanding for dirac-delta for autocorrelation is that: there is only self correlation that exists in the noise term, there is no correlation between current noise and any one of its lagged noise for the original ARMA model. am I right to think that way?

Comment: @YangKewen you’re welcome, that’s correct.